# Java RSA how to generate different public key?

Tags: java, rsa, public-key

I have a problem with generating public key for RSA in java. I use KeyPairGenerator and I get public, private key, p, q and modulus. It is fine. But everytime public key is a 65537. Is there any posibility to generate different public key each time?

Code:

```
KeyPair keys;
KeyPairGenerator generator;

try {
    generator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
    generator.initialize(1024);
    keys = generator.genKeyPair();
} catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException ex) {}
```

Comment: Show us your code. You must do somthing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The public key can't be simply 65537, since in RSA a public key is a pair (n,e) where n is the modulus and e is the exponent. Typically, the exponent is equal to 65537, and it is the modulus that changes.

So, in order to make sure you are generating different keys every time, check that the modulus is changing.

Comment: modulus, p, q and private key is different every time

Comment: If the modulus is different every time, then the public key will be different every time, too. The exponent e is typically chosen to be 65537. Check step 4 in "Key generation" in the wikipedia article: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_%28algorithm%29

Comment: I am casting RSAPublicKey public = (RSAPublicKey)keys.getPublic(); to get public key I am using .getPublicExponent(). Am I doing it wrong? The same with private key I am using getPrivateExponent()

Comment: @user1068894: What you are doing wrong is talking but not listening. Read the wikipedia article.

Comment: Ok now I get it. RSA key is a pair of this exponent and modulus :) thx:)

Answer (score 3):

The value 65537 is the [commonly used exponent of RSA keys](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/65537_%28number%29). It is nothing unusual that this value is fixed and has no security implications.

There are a number of known weak exponents known - but this value does not belong to it.